# Redirect urls in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Given a domain:

```
http://example.com
```

Using .htaccess file, I want to redirect all urls to http://example.com/dummypage.html except those ones containing the pattern "a1", "b1", and "c1". For instance:

```
http://example.com
http://example.com/d1
```

would be redirected. But

```
http://example.com/a1
http://example.com/b1
http://example.com/c1
http://example.com/a1/anything/...
http://example.com/b1/anything/...
http://example.com/c1/anything/...
```

should not be redirected. I tried to compose rules following other answers given here in stack-overflow, but with no success. One should note that other RewriteCond and RewriteRule statements have already been declared on the .htaccess file. Thus, I don't know whether they're influencing the redirection result. The .htaccess file is something like this one: https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule with a negative lookahead regex in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:a1|b1|c1|dummypage\.html)(?:/.*)?\S*\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /dummypage.html [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: It didn't work. Also, I had to add "dummypage.html" to the regex rule in order to stop getting "multiple redirection" error from browser.

Comment: Do you have other rules also in your .htaccess?